# PyPi is adding dashes "-" to the beginning and end of version name

Tags: python, upload, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm trying to upload my package onto PyPI but it will not work.  It looks like `PyPi` or `setuptools` is adding `-` before and after my version name.  Originally, I had the following version: `ß-2018.8` but I don't think unicode characters work.  I then moved it to `beta-2018.8` but that didn't work either.  I even tried a basic `2018.8` but still the same error?!

Can anyone help me figure out what is happening?

My pip version:

```
pip 18.0 from /Users/mu/anaconda/envs/py3_clone/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

My command:

```
python setup.py register sdist upload
```

My error:

```
Submitting dist/thisismypackagename--2018.08-.tar.gz to 

https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (400): '-2018.08-' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Start and end with a letter or numeral containing only ASCII numeric and '.', '_' and '-'. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata
error: Upload failed (400): '-2018.08-' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Start and end with a letter or numeral containing only ASCII numeric and '.', '_' and '-'. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata
```

My `__init__.py`:

```
# =======
# Version
# =======
__version__="beta-2018.08"
```

My `setup.py`

```
import re
from setuptools import setup

# Version
version = None
with open("./thisismypackagename/__init__.py", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("__version__"):
            version = line.split("=")[-1].strip()

setup(name='thisismypackagename',
      version=version,
      description='package description',
      author='Josh L. Espinoza',
      packages=["thisismypackagename"],
      zip_safe=False)
```

This is my directory structure:

```
thisismypackagename
    | thisismypackagename
    | thisismypackagename | __init__.py
    | setup.py
```

Comment: Why are you treating `__init__.py` like an ordinary text file instead of importing `thisismypackagename` and simply getting the value of `thisismypackagename.__version__`?

Comment: That's what `skbio` does and I was using theirs as a reference since this is my first package: https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: You should follow the PyPA tutorial, instead of picking a random package and trying to figure out what they do and reproduce it; it will be a lot simpler, and you avoid the risks of doing something hacky just because you’re following someone else who didn’t know what they were doing.

Comment: Also, 'beta-2018.08' is probably not a good version name. You want your versions to be parseable and orderable (so 2018.08 comes after its beta, not before) by relatively stupid software, which means you want to follow the rules that such software is expecting. These rules are documented, and explained in the tutorial, but IIRC, the only thing those tools know how to deal with besides whole-string comparison is dotted numbers with one final non-numeric trailer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the double quotes around the version:

```
version = None
with open("./thisismypackagename/__init__.py", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("__version__"):
            version = line.split("=")[-1].strip()
print version
# "beta-2018.08"
```

And PyPI is substituting double quotes to  dashes. Get rid of double quotes and problem solves:

```
version = line.split("=")[-1].strip().strip('"')
```